# Google Maps API v3 - Overlay image over whole map (behind marker)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map implemented via the Google Maps API v3. And I just want to add an overlay with a image that covers the whole map, is stretched to 100% width and height of the map container and appears behind the marker and controls. I've searched a long time, but I can't find a solution for this. How can I achieve this?